# How to import orders data on WooCommerce to Shopify migration?

Tags: shopify

I have some doubts regarding WooCommerce to Shopify migration. Can you suggest some solutions for that?

I have tried to import data for WooCommerce to Shopify using the **Store Importer app**. But that gives only product, customer, and collection. But I need old order as well.

Do you have any idea on how to import order data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an automated migration tool? There are plenty of these tools on the market and most of them offer a free demo. The huge advantage of an automated migration is that you can cope with it yourself. No extra skills are needed. I usually go with [Cart2Cart](https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/), it helped me a lot when I was migrating my database from Magento to Shopify. I had a relatively big store with 6000+ products, customers, orders, and even reviews and all the related data. The whole process took about 4-5 hours to complete. I checked the result and everything was okay. You can also check this service, maybe it will suit you too. They offer an extensive list of the supported data